# PagedList Search suffering from inefficiency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pagedlist

I'm trying to achieve Search functionality on more than 10 thousand records. This is suffering from speed issues while using PagedList.

```
public ActionResult CrmBlogGroupType(int? page, bool? Name, bool? AuthorTitle, bool?    Description, string search, int? PageSize, string type)
{
    try
    {
    if (type==null)
    {
        type = "A";
    }
    IEnumerable<Usp_getBlogSetPosts_Result> _objBlogSet = _dataLayer.GetBlogSet(type);
    //The above _objBlogSet has around 10 thousand records

    ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;

    ViewBag.Name = Name ==null?false:Name;
    ViewBag.AuthorTitle = AuthorTitle == null ? false : AuthorTitle;
    ViewBag.Description = Description == null ? false : Description;

    ViewBag.Search = search;
    ViewBag.type = type;

    if (Name == true && AuthorTitle == false && Description == false)
    {
        _objBlogSet = _objBlogSet.Where(p => p.author_name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToPagedList(page ?? 1, PageSize ?? 10);
    } 

    return View(_objBlogSet);

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using Troy Goode's Paged List (https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList)

Instead of working with IEnumerable, try to work with IQueryable.
That way, pagination is done on the server side and performance will be better.

Comment: public List<Tbl_MVPConsultant> Get_MVP_Consultants()
        {
            List<Tbl_MVPConsultant> obj_Consultants = _dbContext.Tbl_MVPConsultant.Where(p => p.Visibility == true).ToList();
            return obj_Consultants;
        }

Above is the Datalayer Method where I get the data.. How can I modify that code to IQueryable..

Comment: do not convert that do list. As soon as you do that, the db gets hit and everything is returned.

Comment: Hi @lusocoding I followed your advice and changed my Datalayer method to return IQueryable Result.. But ToPagedList() method doesn't allowing the Iqueryable Result .. How to proceed now..

Comment: Why are you saying it doesn't allow the IQueryable? What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Hi @lusocoding,
here's the datalayer code:
    IQueryable<Tbl_MVPConsultant> _objConsultants     =_datalayer.Get_MVP_Consultants();

This is where I get the error,
_objConsultants = _objConsultants.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(SearchTextbox.ToLower())).ToPagedList(pagenumber ?? 1, PageSize ?? 5);

and the error is
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Tbl_MVPConsultant>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Tbl_MVPConsultant>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Hi @Dathatreya. You can't assign to the same object _objConsultants the result of the PagedList since that will return a IPagedList. Just do: var result = _objConsultants.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(SearchTextbox.ToLower())).ToPagedList(pagenumber ?? 1, PageSize ?? 5);

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what happens in `_dataLayer.GetBlogSet()`. Your current code most likely pulls in the entire table and filters on that data in-memory.

That method should return an `IQueryable<Usp_getBlogSetPosts_Result>`, so the `ToPagedList()`'s internal `Skip()` and `Take()` on that collection will be translated to SQL queries.

Comment: Can you please modify my code so that I can understand.